# How to extract a particular pattern from a file?

Tags: perl, unix, scripting, tcl

I have a file as in below format:

```
#### >>> start of File

Item number - 1
Name xxxx
yyyy
Result PASS

Item number  - 2
Name yyyyy
yyyy
Result FAIL

Item number - 3
NAME ppppp
eeee
rrrrr
Result PASS

#### >>> End of File
```

Now my question is, how I can extract the complete pattern from
`Item number` to `Result` to a file? If
`Result PASS`, I need to print  the `Name` of the pattern.

Comment: Is `Item number` a fixed string that precedes a series of digits, or is it just a series of numbers?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Don't expect people to do all the coding for you. Especially it is _not_ helping if you mention it is urgent. People are helping here voluntarily, so don't put pressure on them.

Comment: For item #3, is the name "ppppp" or "ppppp\neeee\nrrrrr"?

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -00nE 'say $1 if /Result\s+PASS/ and /name\s+(.+)/i' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You added a [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl) tag to the question, so a tcl answer.

Given what you've shown, I would treat the file as a tcl script containing domain-specific commands -- execute the "script" in a safe interpreter

```
set safe [interp create -safe]
interp share "" stdout $safe        ;# give the safe interp access to stdout
interp eval $safe {                 ;# set up the DSL
    proc unknown args {}
    proc Name args {set ::name [join $args]}
    proc Result result {if {$result eq "PASS"} {puts $::name}}
}
interp alias $safe NAME $safe Name  ;# oops, need better control over the data

# do it
interp invokehidden $safe source ./file
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `vim`. It's enought to run it from command line:

```
vim -c '

    while 1

        let l_result = search( "\\v\\c^result\\s+pass\\s*$", "W" )

        if l_result == 0
            break
        endif

        let l_name = search( "\\v\\c^name\\s+", "b" )

        let name_l_str = getline( l_name ) 

        call cursor( l_name, 1 ) 

        . write! >> outfile

        call setpos( ".", [0, l_result + 1, 1, 0] )

    endwhile

    q!

' infile
```

It yields:

```
Name xxxx
NAME ppppp
```

Steps:

- Search the line which result is "pass".
- Check not EOF.
- Search backwards for the line with the name.
- Get the content of the line.
- Set cursor in the line with the name.
- Print it to an output file.
- Return to cursor to next line of last match of a successful result line
- Close file.

Answer (score -1):

If the file is not too big and you have a set number of lines, you could take the whole file in memory (in an array) and then parse the array and where you find PASS output the previous 4 lines.